# How to flip an object without changing its position in Python

Tags: python

I am a Blender novice and working with an imported model with the layout below:
[image]

What I want to do is rotate the bladed object so that its position and angle with respect to the plane below is exactly the same but the object points in a different direction, like upside down or rolled at a 90 degrees. I'm trying to do it in Python so that its a loop and I could render at intervals- like at 10 degree rotation, 20 degrees, etc- as if you were turning a knob.

I've tried playing with the rotation XYZ but that keeps changing the positioning and I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks

Edit:
Here is the code for the instrument specifically:

```
bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].location=(0,0,25)
bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].rotation_euler[0] = radians(130)
bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].rotation_euler[1] = radians(10)
bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].rotation_euler[2] = radians(20)

R1 = (bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].location[0]**2+bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].location[1]**2)**(1/2)   
range_handle =  range(math.floor(R1)-3,math.floor(R1)+8)             

for n in range(200,330,15):                                      
    for idx in range(len(range_handle)):                
        angle = radians(n)
    
        r1 = range_handle[idx]
    
        x1 = r1*math.cos(angle)
        y1 = r1*math.sin(angle)
    
        bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].location=(x1,y1,25)                                                                                       
        bpy.data.objects["keratome_handle"].rotation_euler[2] = radians(90)+angle
```

Comment: and what did u try so far? maybe share you code...?

Comment: I don't have access to my code right now but I tried playing around with orientations and relations to fix the object but couldn't figure that out.

Comment: I added my code snippet to the post